# how make css animation with box-shadow

Tags: css, animation, box-shadow

I need a CSS animation where part of a line (200px) is replaced with another color (like a gradient). How can I do this?

Here is my current code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.lineHolder {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: darkslateblue;
  box-shadow: 200px 0px 200px -120px blueviolet inset;
  animation: background 5s infinite alternate-reverse linear, background2 8s infinite alternate-reverse linear;
}

@keyframes background {
  0% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
  10% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 200px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
  20% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 400px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
  30% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 600px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
  40% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 800px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
  50% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 1000px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
  60% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 1200px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
  70% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 1400px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
  80% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 1600px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
  90% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 1800px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
  100% {
    background: darkslateblue;
    box-shadow: 2000px 0px 200px -120px lightblue inset;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <h1>Run color line</h1>
  <div class="lineHolder">
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works correctly on this [site](https://www.esri.com/ru-ru/home) near the footer

Comment: what is the current issue with your code? it's seems to be fine

Comment: This is just a rip of the code from the website you linked http://jsfiddle.net/ojwekp82/4/

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'd guess they want it to not bounce back but to appear to keep going

Comment: I shared a link on site where it works fine. I need effect such as run only a fixed part of line

Comment: @repetiy1983 did you see my comment?

Comment: Yes, thanks I did not understand how to copy the effect

Answer (score 0):

The site you linked does not use `box-shadow` to animate, it uses `background-image` paired with `gradients`.

If you don't need the box-shadow for a specific reason here is a working codepen of what I understood you needed: https://codepen.io/matteopieroni/pen/pKmVVy

A piece of advice would be to use different colors, I think the ones you are trying to use are too "close" to give the nice effect of the site you linked. In the pen you can uncomment the second `background-image` line to see how it looks with different colors.

Comment: I understood, when started doing it and found an article that the gradient would be difficult to do such and started through box-shadow

Comment: On the codepen you can see the exact code to replicate what is on the site you linked but with your other css. Is that what you are trying to achieve or is there something I am missing? Can you explain with a picture maybe?

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to do, but I tried it through the shadow-box. Thanks again. I would like to understand  through the shadow-box  is it possible to realize the same ...

Comment: With box-shadow you cannot set a percentage value, therefore you cannot control how far the gradient should go, and would have to write specifica animations for every screen size. Is there a reason why you want to use box-shadow instead of backgrouynd gradient?